# Shortest Unique Substrings

Tags: code-golf, string

## Input

An alphanumeric string `s`.

## Output

The shortest string that occurs exactly once as a (contiguous) substring in `s`.
Overlapping occurrences are counted as distinct.
If there are several candidates of the same length, you must output all of them in the order of occurrence.
In this challenge, the empty string occurs `n + 1` times in a string of length `n`.

## Example

Consider the string

```
"asdfasdfd"
```

The empty string occurs 10 times in it, so it is not a candidate for unique occurrence.
Each of the letters `"a"`, `"s"`, `"d"`, and `"f"` occurs at least twice, so they are not candidates either.
The substrings `"fa"` and `"fd"` occur only once and in this order, while all other substrings of length 2 occur twice.
Thus the correct output is

```
["fa","fd"]
```

## Rules

Both functions and full programs are allowed, and standard loopholes are not.
The exact formatting of the output is flexible, within reason.
In particular, producing no output for the empty string is allowable, but throwing an error is not.
The lowest byte count wins.

## Test cases

```
"" -> [""]
"abcaa" -> ["b","c"]
"rererere" -> ["ererer"]
"asdfasdfd" -> ["fa","fd"]
"ffffhhhhfffffhhhhhfffhhh" -> ["hffff","fffff","hhhhh","hfffh"]
"asdfdfasddfdfaddsasadsasadsddsddfdsasdf" -> ["fas","fad","add","fds"]
```

## Leaderboard

Here's the by-language leaderboard that I promised.

To make sure that your answer shows up, please start your answer with a headline, using the following Markdown template:

```
# Language Name, N bytes
```

where `N` is the size of your submission. If you improve your score, you *can* keep old scores in the headline, by striking them through. For instance:

```
# Ruby, <s>104</s> <s>101</s> 96 bytes
```

```html
<script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'></script><script>site = 'meta.codegolf',postID = 5314,isAnswer = true,QUESTION_ID = 45056;jQuery(function(){var u='https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/';if(isAnswer)u+='answers/'+postID+'?order=asc&sort=creation&site='+site+'&filter=!GeEyUcJFJeRCD';else u+='questions/'+postID+'?order=asc&sort=creation&site='+site+'&filter=!GeEyUcJFJO6t)';jQuery.get(u,function(b){function d(s){return jQuery('<textarea>').html(s).text()};function r(l){return new RegExp('<pre class="snippet-code-'+l+'\\b[^>]*><code>([\\s\\S]*?)<\\/code><\/pre>')};b=b.items[0].body;var j=r('js').exec(b),c=r('css').exec(b),h=r('html').exec(b);if(c!==null)jQuery('head').append(jQuery('<style>').text(d(c[1])));if (h!==null)jQuery('body').append(d(h[1]));if(j!==null)jQuery('body').append(jQuery('<script>').text(d(j[1])))})})</script>
```

Comment: Any limitations on combinatorial built-in functions?

Comment: @MartinBüttner In this challenge, everything goes. If this gets enough answers, I'll put up a by-language leaderboard, so even the more ill-equipped languages can have a meaningful competition.

Comment: Do you want to use [my code golf leaderboard snippet](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/43048/8478)? Then you wouldn't have to monitor all edits to keep the leaderboard up-to-date. If you do, I can add it for you, and I'd go through the answers to make them match the header format.

Comment: @MartinBüttner Thanks, I'd appreciate that!

Comment: All done! Let me know if something doesn't work. (Feel free to reuse it for your challenges in the future.)

Comment: You should specify `target="_top"` on your links. Currently, you can't change to another question since it opens inside the iframe.

Comment: You can also say the empty string occurs 0 or 1000 times in a 10-char string, are you trying to recreate [ether](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminiferous_aether)?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I have to admit that I don't understand how the snippet works (it's courtesy of Matrin Büttner), so I can't fix it. But if you middle-click or Ctrl-click on the links, the answers open in new tabs, at least on Firefox. You can also just re-run the snippet to get the leaderboard back.

Comment: @lolesque The justification for the number `n+1` is that I think of the substrings of a string as beginning and ending "between" the characters. For example, a suffix of length `2` begins right before the second-to-last character, and ends right after the last one. The empty substring begins and ends at the same place, and there are `n+1` possible places for it.

Comment: I'm aware of that. I'm just pointing out an issue.

Comment: Shouldn't `""` -> `[]` as `""` occurs infinite times in `""`?

Comment: @Reticality As I explain above, for the purposes of this challenge I _define_ that `""` occurs exactly `n+1` times in a string of length `n`. In particular, it occurs in `""` exactly once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Pyth, <s>27</s> 26 bytes

```
&zhfTmf!/>zhxzYYm<>zkdUzUz
```

[Try it here.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/)

Note that due to a bug in the online compiler, the empty string case only works correctly on the command line version, which can be found [here.](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth)

You can also cure the bug by giving a newline as the input for the online compiler.

#### Explanation:

```
                                   z = input(), implicit.
&z                                 Prints empty string if input is empty.
  hfT                              Take the first non-empty list from
     m                  Uz         A list of list of substrings of z, divided by length
                m<>zkdUz           with some shorter strings repeated later, to no effect.
      f                            Where the substrings are filtered on
       !/      Y                   There being 0 occurrences of the substring in
         >z                        The slice of z
           hxzY                    from the character after the first character
                                   of the first occurrence of the substring in z
                                   to the end of z.
```

Comment: Fails for empty string input.

Comment: @Optimizer I think that's a bug in the online compiler, actually. It works on the command line version. In fact, `z` on no input fails online, so it's definitely a bug in the interpreter.

Comment: Doesn't give EOF ?

Comment: @Optimizer Pyth expects newline terminated input, which might be what is going wrong.

Comment: So passing an empty string is not even possible ?

Comment: @Optimizer If you want to test that case online, put a newline in the input field.

Answer (score 13):

## Python 3, <s>124</s> <s>123</s> <s>111</s> 96 bytes

```py
f=lambda s,n=1:[x for x in[s[i:i+n]for i in range(len(s)+1)]if s.find(x)==s.rfind(x)]or f(s,n+1)
```

Looks for strings such that the first occurrence from the left is the same as the first occurrence from the right. The `+1` in the `range` is to accommodate for the empty string case.

Now if only Python had a `.count()` which counted *overlapping* matches, then this would have been a fair bit shorter.

Answer (score 6):

## Mathematica, <s>95</s> <s>94</s> 79 bytes

```
Cases[Tally@StringCases[#,___,Overlaps->All],{s_,1}:>s]~MinimalBy~StringLength&
```

`StringCases` gets me all possible substrings, the `Tally` and `Cases` filter out those that appear more than once and `MinimalBy` finds those that are shortest.

Comment: Isn't there an extra `&` at the end of the code?

Comment: Boy, you're fast!

Answer (score 4):

### GolfScript, 44 bytes

```
:S;-1:x{;S,x):x-),{S>x<}%:^1/{^\/,2=},.!}do`
```

Takes input as a string on stdin and outputs in a double-array syntax: e.g. `[["b"] ["c"]]`. [Online demo](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=IyMgVGVzdCBmcmFtZXdvcmsKOycKYWJjYWEKcmVyZXJlcmUnbi97CiMjCgo6UzstMTp4eztTLHgpOngtKSx7Uz54PH0lOl4xL3teXC8sMj19LC4hfWRvYAoKIyMgVGVzdCBmcmFtZXdvcmsKcHV0c30vCiMj)

#### Dissection

```
:S;          # Store input in S and pop it
-1:x         # Store -1 in x
{            # do-while loop
  ;          #   Pop x the first time and [] every subsequent time
  S,x):x-),  #   Increment x and build an array [0 1 ... len(S)-x]
  {S>x<}%    #   Map that array to [substr(S,0,x) substr(S,1,x) ...]
  :^         #   Store in ^ (to avoid the token coalescing with the next char)
  1/         #   Split by length 1 to iterate over 1-elt arrays rather than strings
  {^\/,2=},  #   Filter to arrays which occur exactly once as a subarray of ^
  .!         #   Duplicate and test emptiness
}do          # end do-while loop: loop if the filtered array is empty
`            # Stringify for output
```

This is arranged such that no special case is required for the empty string (which I've included as a test case in the online demo linked above).

Answer (score 3):

## Java, 168 <s>176 233</s>

Here's a pretty basic nested loop example.

```java
void n(String s){for(int l=0,i=0,t=s.length(),q=0;l++<t&q<1;i=0)for(String b;i<=t-l;)if(s.indexOf(b=s.substring(i,i+++l),s.indexOf(b)+1)<0){System.out.println(b);q++;}}
```

Or a *bit* more readable:

```java
void t(String s){
    for(int l=0,i=0,t=s.length(),q=0;l++<t&q<1;i=0)
        for(String b;i<=t-l;)
            if(s.indexOf(b=s.substring(i,i++ +l),s.indexOf(b)+1)<0){
                System.out.println(b);
                q++;
            }
}
```

Comment: If you want readability, splitting `+++` up to show whether it's `+ ++` or `++ +` would help... And if you want to save a few more bytes, there might be a way to do that by initialising `q=1`, replacing `q++` with `q=t`, and replacing `l++<t&q<1` with something like `t>l+=q`. Probably requires tweaking one or two other offsets to get it to work.

Comment: @Peter Well, by readable I mostly meant "I don't have to horizontally scroll," but I clarified the `+++`. I've been trying to tweak it (especially `q`, which feels somewhat wasteful), but haven't found anything solid yet.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Due to the lexing rules of Java, `+++` always resolves to `++ +`.

Comment: @FUZxxl, I doubt that even most Java users know that, and there are lots of people on this site who don't know Java.

Comment: Using indexOf with offset instead of lastIndexOf should cut 1 byte (see my javascript answer)

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 109 <s>110</s>

**Edit** search instead of indexOf, as the input string is alphanumeric. Thanks @IsmaelMiguel

Recursive function, looking for substrings starting with length 1 and going up.

```js
F=(s,n=1,r)=>
s?[...s].map((a,i)=>~s.indexOf(a=s.substr(i,n),s.search(a)+1)?r:r=[...r||[],a])&&r||F(s,n+1):[s]
```

**Ungolfed** and explained

```js
 F = function(s, n=1) { // start with length 1
   var i, a, p, r;
   if (s == "") // special case for empty input string
     return [s];
   for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) 
   // for each possibile substring of length n
   // (should stop at s.length-n+1 but going beyond is harmless)
   // Golfed: "[...s].map((a,i)" ... using i, a is overwrittem
   {
     a = s.substr(i, n); // substring at position i
     p = s.search(a); // p is the first position of substring found, can be i or less
     p = s.indexOf(a, p + 1) // p is now the position of a second instance of substring, or -1 if not found
     if (~p) // ~p is 0 if p is -1
     {
       ; // found more than once, do nothing
     }
     else
     {
       r = r || []; // if r is undefined, then it becomes an empty array
       r.push(a); // save substring 
       // Golfed: "r=[...r||[],a]"
     }
   }
   if (r) // if found some substring, saved in r
   {
     return r;
   }
   return F(s, n+1) // recursive retry for a bigger length
 }
```

**Test** In FireFox/FireBug console

```
;["", "abcaa", "rererere", "asdfasdfd", "ffffhhhhfffffhhhhhfffhhh", 
 "asdfdfasddfdfaddsasadsasadsddsddfdsasdf"]
.forEach(x=>console.log(x,F(x)))
```

*Output*

```
 [""]
abcaa ["b", "c"]
rererere ["ererer"]
asdfasdfd ["fa", "fd"]
ffffhhhhfffffhhhhhfffhhh ["hffff", "fffff", "hhhhh", "hfffh"]
asdfdfasddfdfaddsasadsasadsddsddfdsasdf ["fas", "fad", "add", "fds"]
```

Comment: Use `.search` instead of `.indexOf` and you save 2 bytes.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel no because 1) search has not a offset parameter 2) search expect a regexp, and will fail with special chars like .*[] and so on

Comment: But on the first you can safely replace it (on your `s.indexOf(a)+1`). While it's tue it won't work with those chars, you dont have to worry! Quoting the O.P: "`Input: An alphanumeric string s.`"

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel right, thanks. Missed the 'alphanumeric' constrain

Comment: You're welcome. Your code is shorter now, which makes it better. I'm pretty sure it can be golfed a bit. But can't see anything....

Comment: If you change your function defition from `F=(s,n=1,r)=>` to `F=(s,n=1,r=[])=>`, will it work as expected? If it does, you can remove the `||[]` part ahead, shaving off another byte. I read about default parameters here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24197306/how-do-functions-defined-in-my-firebug-console-accept-default-parameters

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I did not find a way ... I need truthy or falsy, and any array (even empty []) is a truthy value in javascript

Comment: I understand now. If you don't mind the bad side effects that will happen, you may use `r=[];F=(s,n=1)=>
s?[...s].map((a,i)=>~s.indexOf(a=s.substr(i,n),s.search(a)+1)?r:r=[...r,a])&&r||F(s,n+1):[s]` instead. The side effect is that `r` will have all the previous results from the last time you ran the code. But it works and you shave off a byte. There is nothing in the question saying your code is meant to run *n* times in a row and must always return the correct result. This is rule-bending. If you want, you may add this as a note.

Answer (score 3):

### J, <s>61</s> <s>58</s> <s>44</s> <s>42</s> <s>40</s> <s>38</s> 37 bytes

```
[:>@{.@(#~#@>)#\<@(~.#~1=#/.~)@(]\)]
```

Here is a version split up into the individual components of the solution:

```
unqs =. ~. #~ 1 = #/.~               NB. uniques; items that appear exactly once
allsbsq =. #\ <@unqs@(]\) ]        NB. all unique subsequences
shrtsbsq =. [: >@{.@(#~ #@>) allsbsq NB. shortest unique subsequence
```

- `x #/. y` computes for each distinct element in `x` how often in occurs in `y`.  If we use this as `y #/. y`, we get the for each distinct element in `y` its count. For instance, `a #/. a` for `a =. 1 2 2 3 4 4` yields `1 2 1 2`.
- `1 = y` checks which items of `y` are equal to `1`. For instance, `1 = a #/. a` yields `1 0 1 0`.
- `u~` is the *reflexive* of a monadic verb `u`. This is, `u~ y` is the same as `y u y`. Thus, `#/.~ y` is the same as `#/.~ y`. When applied to a dyadic verb, `u~` is the *passive*  of `u`. That is, `x u~ y` is the same as `y u x`. These are used in quite a few other places which I do not explicitly mention.
- `~. y` is the *nub* of `y`, a vector with duplicates removed. For instance, `~. a` yields `1 2 3 4`.
- `x # y` (*copy*) selects from `y` the items at the indices where `x` contains a `1`.
- Thus, `(1 = y #/. y) # (~. y)` creates a vector of those elements of `y` which appear only once. In tacit notation, this verb is written as `~. #~ 1 = #/.~`; let's call this phrase `unqs` for the rest of the explanation.
- `x ]\ y` creates an `x` by `1 + y - x` array of all *infixes* of the vector `y` of length `x`. For instance, `3 ]\ 'asdfasdfd` yields

  ```
  asd
  sdf
  dfa
  fas
  asd
  sdf
  dfd
  ```
- `# y` is the *tally* of `y`, that is, the number of elements in `y`.
- `u\ y` applies `u` to each *prefix* of `y`. Incidentally, `#\ y` creates a vector of integers from `1` to `#y`.
- `< y` puts `y` into a box. This is needed because arrays cannot be ragged and we compute an array of suffixes of different lengths; a boxed array counts as a scalar.
- Thus, `(i. # y) <@:unqs@(]\) y` generates a vector of `#y` boxed arrays of the length *k* (for all 0 ≤ *k* < `#y`) infixes of *y* that occur exactly once. The tacit form of this verb is `i.@# <@unqs@(]\) ]` or `i.@# <@(~. #~ 1 = #/.~)@(]\) ]` if we don't use the `unqs` name. Let's call this phrase `allsbsq` for the rest of this explanation. For instance, `allsbsq 'asdfasdfd'` yields:

  ```
  ┌┬─┬──┬───┬────┬─────┬──────┬───────┬────────┐
  ││ │fa│dfa│sdfa│asdfa│asdfas│asdfasd│asdfasdf│
  ││ │fd│fas│dfas│sdfas│sdfasd│sdfasdf│sdfasdfd│
  ││ │  │dfd│fasd│dfasd│dfasdf│dfasdfd│        │
  ││ │  │   │sdfd│fasdf│fasdfd│       │        │
  ││ │  │   │    │asdfd│      │       │        │
  └┴─┴──┴───┴────┴─────┴──────┴───────┴────────┘
  ```
- `(#@> y) # y` takes from vector of boxed arrays `y` those which aren't empty.
- `{. y` takes the first element of vector `y`.
- `> y` removes the box from `y`.
- Thus, `> {. (#@> y) # y` yields the unboxed first non-empty array from vector of boxed arrays `y`. This phrase is written `>@{.@(#~ #@>)` in tacit notation.
- Finally, `[: >@{.@(#~ #@>) allsbsq` assembles the previous phrase with `allsbsq` to create a solution to the problem we have. Here is the full phrase with spaces:

  ```
  [: >@{.@(#~ #@>) i.@# <@(~. #~ 1 = #/.~)@(]\) ]
  ```

Answer (score 3):

## Scala, 120 bytes

```
readLine.inits.flatMap(_.tails).toList.groupBy(l=>l).filter(x=>x._2.length<2).map(_._1).groupBy(_.length).minBy(_._1)._2
```

I started off with 140 which at least already fits into a tweet.

```
(                                        // added for comments
 readLine                                // input
.inits.flatMap(_.tails).toList           // get all substrings of that string
.groupBy(l=>l).filter(x=>x._2.length<2)  // remove substrings that occur more than once
.map(_._1).groupBy(_.length)             // take the substring and group by length
.minBy(_._1)._2                          // take the list of shortest substrings
)
```

Comment: I wonder? Why doesn't just `(_)` work as the identity instead of `l=>l`?

Comment: I wonder too. Somehow `list.groupBy(_)` is the same as `x => list.groupBy(x)`. I have no idea why they implemented it like that.

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, <s>52 43</s> 40 bytes

```
]]q:Q,,{)Q,1$-),f{Q><}:R{R\a/,2=},}%{}=p
```

Input is the string without quotes

**Explanation**:

```
]]                                       "For empty string input case";
  q:Q                                    "Read the input and store in Q";
     ,,                                  "Take length of input and 0 to length array";
       {                          }%     "Map the above array on this code block";
        )Q                               "Increment the number in the current iteration, L";
         Q,1$                            "Take input's length and copy the above number";
             -)                          "Get upper limit of next loop to get substrings";
               ,f{   }                   "Get 0 to above number array and for each";
                  Q><                    "Get the L length substring at Ith index where";
                                         "I loops from 0 to Q, - L + 1";
                      :R                 "Store this list of substring of length L in R";
                        {R\a/,2=},       "Filter to get unique substrings";
                                    {}=  "Get the first non empty substring array";
                                         "This leaves nothing on stack if all are empty";
                                       p "Print the top stack element. At this point, its";
                                         "Either the first non empty substring array or";
                                         "the ]] i.e. [""] which we added initially";
```

Example:

```
asdfdfasddfdfaddsasadsasadsddsddfdsasdf
```

Output

```
["fas" "fad" "add" "fds"]
```

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Answer (score 3):

## Haskell, <strike>169</strike> <strike>162</strike>  <strike>155</strike> <strike>153</strike> <strike>151</strike>  <strike>138</strike> <strike>120</strike> 115

```
import Data.List
l=length
q k=filter$(==)k.l
p y=q(minimum.map l$y)$y
f x=p$concat$q 1$group$sort$(tails x>>=inits)
```

To use it:

```
f "asdfdfasddfdfaddsasadsasadsddsddfdsasdf"
```

Which gives:

```
["add","fad","fas","fds"]
```

<strike>Btw. I hate the last line of my code (repetition of `h y`). Anyone hints to get rid of it?</strike>

Comment: How about you define `g y=q(minimum.(map l)$y)$y` (are the parentheses around `map l` really required?) and then `f=g.concat.q 1.group.sort.concatMap inits.tails`?

Comment: Using `>>=` instead of `concatMap`, i.e. `f x=p$concat$q 1$group$sort$(tails x>>=inits)` saves 2 bytes. Why the `Data.Ord` import?

Comment: The parentheses in `q` are unnecessary, since you can write `filter$(==)k.l`, as are the last `$` and the spaces before the `y`s in `p`. You can also remove the semicolons after the imports (`Data.Ord` seems indeed unnecessary).

Comment: Leksah compiler does not accept `$` followed by a non-space. It will shave of some bytes, but is it in the language spec?

Comment: GHC will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>171</s> <s>152</s> <s>134</s> 125

```php
function f($s){while(!$a&&++$i<strlen($s))for($j=0;$b=substr($s,$j++,$i);)strpos($s,$b)==strrpos($s,$b)&&($a[]=$b);return$a;}
```

http://3v4l.org/RaWTN

Comment: You don't need to explicitly define `$j=0`. Ahead, you have `substr($s,$j++,$i)`. Without defining `$j`, you can rewrite this to `substr($s,0+$j++,$i)` and you save 2 bytes. Why is that? Well, the first time, `$j` will be `null`. And you will effectively be passing `null` to `substr`, which I don't think that will work well. Using `0+$j++` will convert the `null` to `0`. If you see that it isn't needed, go ahead without it and just remove the `$j=0` part.

Comment: Tried that; it doesn't work because PHP doesn't have strong scoping, so `$j` is not cleared and reinitialised for each iteration of the `while()` loop.  So while it's null (and hence would be converted to `0` by a `$j++` call) the first time around, on future iterations of the outer loop it's left at the value it was before.  It's not so much initialising as resetting.  Thanks for the suggestion though :-)

Comment: Here I offer you a 141 bytes long solution: `function f($s){$l=strlen($s);while(!$a&&++$i<$l)for($j=0;$j<$l;)($b=substr($s,$j++,$i))&(strpos($s,$b)==strrpos($s,$b)&&($a[]=$b));return$a;}` Changes: Removed ALL your `||1`, used the bitwise `&` (`AND`) instead of `&&` in one place, moved the `$j<$l&&[...]` part outside the `for` (saving 2 bytes) and removed some unnecessary parenthesys.

Comment: One 134 bytes long gift for you: `function f($s){$l=strlen($s);while(!$a&&++$i<$l)for($j=0;$j<$l;)strpos($s,$b=substr($s,$j++,$i))==strrpos($s,$b)&&($a[]=$b);return$a;}` Changes made to the previous code: moved the `$b=substr($s,$j++,$i)` into `strpos($s,$b)` making it `strpos($s,$b=substr($s,$j++,$i))`, removed more unecessary parenthesys and removed the unneeded `&`.

Comment: I think it will be hard to reduce the size further. You can leave the old solution to show what you had and what you have now.

Comment: Managed a little more chopping :-)  `substr($s,$j++,$i)` returns `""` when `$j` reaches the length of the string, and `false` thereafter, so that assignment can also serve as the loop conditional break.  Then there's only one use of `$l` remaining, so that can be consolidated as well.

Comment: Nice one! Now, lets bend rules! Since the rules say that `Both functions and full programs are allowed, and standard loopholes are not.`, you can remove the whole `function f($s){` part. Then you use this: `while(!$a&&++$i<strlen($s=$_GET[s]))for($j=0;$b=substr($s,$j++,$i);)strpos($s,$b)==strrpos($s,$b)&&($a[]=$b);print_r($a);` which is 121 bytes long now. You have to explain that it is required to send a URL parameter named `s` with the string while accessing the file over the browser. Example: `a.php?s=YourStringHere`. It will throw warnings but the O.P. didn't said they weren't allowed!

Comment: Instead of `$_GET[s]` you can use `$argv[1]` which receives the string though standard input. You may need more testing, but both solutions should work fine.

Comment: If I did that, I would need to change the `return $a` statement to a `print_r($a)`, which would use up all bar one of the bytes saved.  Can't return an array either from a shell script or web request.

Comment: If you notice the code I provided you, it already has the `print_r` there.

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 135 Bytes

```
import Data.List
f ""=[""]
f g=map(snd)$head$groupBy(\a b->fst a==fst b)$sort[(length y,y)|[y]<-group$sort[x|x@(_:_)<-tails g>>=inits]]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Rebol, 136 bytes

```
f: func[s][repeat n length? b: copy s[unless empty? x: collect[forall s[unless find next find b t: copy/part s n t[keep t]]][return x]]]
```

Ungolfed:

```
f: func [s] [
    repeat n length? b: copy s [
        unless empty? x: collect [
            forall s [
                unless find next find b t: copy/part s n t [keep t]
            ]
        ][return x]
    ]
]
```

Usage example:

```
>> f ""       
== none

>> f "abcaa"
== ["b" "c"]

>> f "rererere"
== ["ererer"]

>> f "asdfasdfd"
== ["fa" "fd"]

>> f "ffffhhhhfffffhhhhhfffhhh"
== ["hffff" "fffff" "hhhhh" "hfffh"]

>> f "asdfdfasddfdfaddsasadsasadsddsddfdsasdf"
== ["fas" "fad" "add" "fds"]
```

NB. I suppose the heart of the code is how the [`find`](http://www.rebol.com/r3/docs/functions/find.html) part is working.  Hopefully this will help explain...

```
>> find "asdfasdfd" "df"
== "dfasdfd"

>> next find "asdfasdfd" "df"
== "fasdfd"

>> find next find "asdfasdfd" "df" "df"
== "dfd"

>> ;; so above shows that "df" is present more than once - so not unique
>> ;; whereas below returns NONE because "fa" found only once - ie. bingo!

>> find next find "asdfasdfd" "fa" "fa"
== none
```

Answer (score 2):

## Groovy (Java regex on Oracle implementation), 124

```
c={m=it=~/(?=(.*?)(?=(.*))(?<=^(?!.*\1(?!\2$)).*))/;o=m.collect({it[1]});o.findAll({it.size()==o.min({it.size()}).size()});}
```

Tested on Groovy 2.4 + Oracle JRE 1.7. The regex should work for Java 6 to Java 8, since the bug that allows the code above to work is not fixed. Not sure for previous version, since there is a look-behind bug in Java 5 which was fixed in Java 6.

The regex finds the shortest string which doesn't have a duplicate substring elsewhere, at every position in the input string. The code outside takes care of filtering.

```
(?=(.*?)(?=(.*))(?<=^(?!.*\1(?!\2$)).*))
```

- Since the strings can overlap, I surround the whole thing in look-ahead `(?=...)`.
- `(.*?)` searches from the shortest substring
- `(?=(.*))` captures the rest of the string to mark the current position.
- `(?<=^(?!.*\1(?!\2$)).*)` is an emulation of variable-length look-behind, which takes advantage of the implementation bug which allows `(?<=.*)` to pass the length check.
- `(?!.*\1(?!\2$))` simply checks that you can't find the same substring elsewhere. The `(?!\2$)` rejects the original position where the substring is matched.

  The limit of the outer look-around construct doesn't apply to the nested look-around construct. Therefore, the nested negative look-ahead `(?!.*\1(?!\2$))` actually checks for the whole string, not just up to the right boundary of the look-behind.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell, 119

```
f s=[r|n<-[1..length s],l<-[map(take n)$take(length s-n+1)$iterate(drop 1)s],r<-[[j|j<-l,[j]==[r|r<-l,r==j]]],r/=[]]!!0
```

Comment: you can put `q = length` somewhere and use `q`, shaves off some bytes

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 10 bytes

```
sᶠ≡ᵍ~gˢlᵍt
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pfXa6koGunoFRu/6htw6Ompoe7Omsfbp3wv/jhtgWPOhc@3Npbl356UQ6QLvn/P1pJSUcpMSk5MRFIF6VCIEioOCUNhFOA7DQgyACCNBgjA0JDlYEVgqmUlOLE4kQokZICFi0GKVGKBQA)

```
sᶠ            The list of every substring of the input
  ≡ᵍ          grouped by identity,
    ~gˢ       with length-1 groups converted to their elements and other groups discarded,
       lᵍ     and grouped by their length,
         t    has the output as its last group.
```

Although `ᵍ` doesn't naturally sort by the value it groups by, instead ordering the groups by the first occurrence of each value, the first occurrences of every length are in decreasing order. I'm not 100% sure that the uniqueness filtering can't mess this up, but I haven't come up with a test case this fails yet.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Œʒ¢}é.γg}н
```

Outputs nothing for an empty string.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6KRTkw4tqj28Uu/c5vTaC3v//08sTkkD4RQA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeWhlf@PTjo16dC64kOLag@v1Du3Ob32wt7/Ov@jlZR0lBKTkhMTgXRRKgSChIpT0kA4BchOA4IMIEiDMTIgNFQZWCGYSkkpTixOhBIpKWDRYpASqB1JySAGCCjFAgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Œ           # Get all substrings of the (implicit) input-String
 ʒ          # Filter it by:
  ¢         #  Count how many times the current substring occurs in the (implicit) input-String
            #  (only 1 is truthy in 05AB1E, so the filter will leave unique substrings)
   }é       # After the filter: sort the remaining substrings by length
     .γg}   # Then group them by length as well
         н  # And only leave the first group containing the shortest substrings
            # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

This takes advantage of 05AB1E's only having `1` as truthy value, and everything else as falsey. The shortest unique substring is always guaranteed to occur exactly once for all possible input-strings. (For an input-string containing only the same characters (i.e. `aaaaa`), the input-strings itself as substring occurs just once, so the result is `["aaaaa"]`. For an input-String with repeating pattern (i.e. `"abcabc"`), there are still unique substrings that only occur once (`["abca","abcab","abcabc","bca","bcab","bcabc","ca","cab","cabc"]`), so this will result in `["ca"]`.)

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 150

```
import re
a=input()
r=range
l=len(a)
d=0
for i in r(l):
 if d:break
 for j in r(l-i):
  k=a[j:i+j+1]
  if len(re.findall("(?="+k+")",a))<2:d=1;print k
```

Comment: Gray area, it should print `""`, but you print nothing.

Comment: @Jakube "The exact formatting of the output is flexible"

Comment: But you have no output at all.

Comment: @Jakube The output is the empty string, just like it's supposed to be. I just don't have quotes around it.

Comment: Well, I don't think so. `print("")` and doing nothing causes different results. The first one prints an empty line. But I don't wanna argue. Probably fine.

Comment: @Jakube I'll allow this, since the empty string is a special case anyway.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-a`, <s>114</s> 87 bytes

```perl
map{//;(grep$' eq$_,@q)-1||($l||=y///c)-y///c||say}@q=map{"@F"=~/(?=(.{$_}))/g}1..y///c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83saBaX99aI70otUBFXSG1UCVex6FQU9ewpkZDJaemxrZSX18/WVMXTNXUFCdW1joU2oJ0KTm4KdnW6WvY22roVavE12pq6qfXGurpgVX@/5@YmJT0L7@gJDM/r/i/rq@pnoGhwX/dRAA)

Old method:
[114 bytes](https://tio.run/##JYxBCoMwEAC/0oZFFGNWD55CMKfe@oYirdWAJCGrlCL5etOUznWG8VNY@5Qe7oB7XUu4KaYvTL4Ws04lCqwOFFlFlMAVFNLvtOjAgZvnibAcFPAKcVaqK4rzHCaPwJFr@oeUQ0l5gzHudjOrDpLGN9OBpTT@@Di/GWcpNddetF2bGjt@AQ)